# Dispose Entity DbContext in WinForms

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In Windows Forms application, when form starts, it loads data from database. It first goes to Persistence Data layer and creates new DBContext.

`public DataEntities DBContext = new DataEntities();`

After this it loads data.

I dispose DBContext on form close event. The reason for that is that I use Local property of DBContext to query data. So it queries memory data after loading and not database which is good (fast). 
The other thing is that only user who starts program has access to his own data (and not data of other users). So there is very little chance anyone can modify his data (only his deputy).

So, DBContext is not disposed until form is closed.

Note 1: this is form for entering data. It is not Main form. On Main Form I will dispose it immidiatelly as Main form is just for viewing data.

Note 2: application will be used in local network and number of users is around 40.

Note 3: I use entity framework 6.1.3

After loading data at start, in sql profiler I noticed sql command is called:

```
exec sp_reset_connection
```

My question is:
Can I use this approach and dispose DBContext when form closes (on form closing event)?

Comment: Because if I would use using block, than I would not be able to use Local property of DBContext as it would be disposed. It would change logic of Save, Add, Delete operations that I wrote.

Comment: normally you have to keep the DbContext live short as possible to avoid a lot of concurrency and caching problems. But in your use you have can use it like that without any problem. My recommendtion keep the DbContext open as long your view is open. For example in winform when you switch a tab Tab if you have a Tab or mainForm then generate your DbContext and keep it alive as long as this view alive

Comment: @Bassam Alugili  Thanks. I also hope I can dispose it on Form close event. On Main form I dispose it immidiatelly as Main form will stay open long time. But this sub forms are for save, edit, delete operations, so I could use it this way. Also, user have access only to his data, so others cannot read and display his data, which will prevent "cant save as someone is holding record". 
The other thing is that I dont understand what is going on with DBContext when it stays opened, whats going under the hood in sql server.

Comment: In this article is explained more in detail
http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html#.U6WdzrGEeTw

Comment: the good thing of this approach is that Entity Framework tracks changes. So if you did not do any change and you click Save button, it will not send update query as there is nothing to save. Entity Framework tracks what needs to be saved. But if you Dispose dbcontext, than I am not sure it would not send large update query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. This is known as a *connected scenario*, i.e. the context stays "connected" (mind the quotes) to the database and you save the same entities as you grabbed from the database.

In a rich client application like a Windows Forms application this is a common pattern for relatively short-lived edit dialog windows. And that's exactly what you're doing here.

The context doesn't actually keep an open connection to the database. It closes the connection after each database interaction, hence the Sql Profiler logging.

One thing to consider. Even though there's little chance that users edit the same data simultaneously, it may be recommended to introduce [optimistic concurrency control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). EF makes this relatively easy.

Answer (score 2):

When your DbContext has a long live time, here are some considerations (Connected entities):

- Each retrieved entity from SQL Server will be loaded into memory in the First Level Cache (RAM USAGE).
- If the data changed from other DbContext, you might get some concurrency issues.
- If your SQL Server TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL is READ UNCOMMITTED then you might get a dirty read.
- If a lot of entities are loaded in the DbContext (Thousands), the application will be generally slower and maybe you will get a performance issues when you try to change an entity beacuse EF has to track them all.